# Vuejs application api login call response gone wrong

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, request, axios

The expected login api response is

```
{"message":"success","data":{"id":2,"name":"name","email":"example@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"nrc":"12\/PABATA(N)7243942","phone_number":"234234234","account_status":"Active","created_at":"2021-01-05T13:37:08.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-05T14:44:08.000000Z","token":"189|1Z6MoqqnM8kd10phzweH0mbZY6CYlAvrkHih4R0G"}}
```

but the actual response from axios was

```
{"email":"example@gmail.com","password":"fwefw324"}{"message":"success","data":{"id":2,"name":"UnionEA","email":"faroakkhan@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"nrc":"12\/PABATA(N)097238","phone_number":"09789333573","account_status":"Active","created_at":"2021-01-05T13:37:08.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-05T14:44:08.000000Z","token":"189|1Z6MoqqnM8kd10phzweH0mbZY6CYlAvrkHih4R0G"}}
```

I was also try from postman but the response got the same what I expected.

JavaScript code is

```
axios.post("/api/login", credentials).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    return dispatch("attempt", response.data.data.token);
  });
```

Laravel code what i calling as api /api/login

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Traits\ResponserTrait;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class LoginApiController extends Controller
{
use ResponserTrait;
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) && 
$user->account_status == config('enums.account_status')['INIT']) {
        return $this- 
>respondCreateMessageOnly(config('enums.account_status')['INIT']);
    }

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) 
{
        return $this->loginFailed('invalid email or password');
    } else {
        $token = $user->createToken('login-user')->plainTextToken;

        $user->token = $token;

        return $this->respondCollection('success', $user);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The one time I saw this one, it was a backend error rather than a frontend issue. It's your API you're using ?

Comment: I used php Laravel as backend. sometime i try in postman. Postman got the response what i expected, but sometime i test the api in isomnia it return like the wrong one

Comment: The response is malformed: seems like a backend issue.

Answer (score 0):

if the response is a string.you can use this code to get the expected response.

```
JSON.parse("{"+response.split("}{")[1])
```